# get pages where user clicked on adsense

Tags: adsense

How can I get the list of pages (of our website) **programatically** in which a user has clicked on google ads?

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate your adsense account with Google Analytics, this is the only way to do that reliably.

[Here is a decent tutorial on how to do this](http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2009-05-02-n20.html)

After you have done this, your Google analytics dashboard will start to show which pages have made you money, and how many clicks they've had.

To do this programatically you would have to use the google analytics API once you had integrated it with adsense.

Comment: @Chris i want to get pages programatically

Comment: There is a Analytics API that will probably do it

Comment: i have checked the analytics api but not found Although this thing can be seen in google analytics web panel.

Comment: In which case it cannot be done easily I'm afraid.  I am pretty sure there were some 3rd party javascript libraries that provided you with this information, but I am not sure if they are [a] still around, [b] still work and [c] they may be in breach of adsense TOC...... Why do you want to know this information programatically?

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider creating a unique ad for each page on your site and use the AdSense API to understand which pages are producing AdSense activity. It would be a lot of work, however. You're better of using the Analytics solution. If their API does not allow you to access this report, you could set it up so that the report is sent to an email address on a periodic basis and have a script setup to pipe that content into your toolset/db.